# Python "NoneType is not callable" error

Tags: python, types

I have a function that looks like the following, with a whole lot of optional parameters.  One of these parameters, somewhere amidst all the others, is `text`.

I handle `text` specially because if it is a boolean, then I want to run to do something based on that.  If it's not (which means it's just a string), then I do something else.  The code looks roughly like this:

```
def foo(self, arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None, ...,  text=None, argN=None, ...):
    ...
    if text is not None:
        if type(text)==bool:
            if text:
                # Do something
            else:
                # Do something else
        else:
            # Do something else
```

I get the following error on the `type(text)==bool` line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...", line 79, in foo
    if type(text)==bool:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Not sure what the problem is.  Should I be testing the type differently?  Experimenting on the python command line seems to confirm that my way of doing it should work.

Comment: do you have an argument called `type`?

Comment: @SilentGhost, should be an answer.

Comment: @Matthew: as you wish :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you have an argument called `type` somewhere, I can easily reproduce your error with the following code:

```
>>> type('abc')
<class 'str'>
>>> type = None
>>> type('abc')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#62>", line 1, in <module>
    type('abc')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have a `type=None` among your arguments.

Just a special case of the general rule: "don't hide built-in identifiers with your own -- it may or may not bite in any specific give case, but it **will** bite you nastily in some cases in the future unless you develop the right habit about it"!-)